# custom xsd schema validation using spring validator

Tags: java, spring, xsd-validation, custom-validators

This is my first post to this forum.

I have a xml that represents a list of pnr (flight) bookings. Inside this it has got a list of individual pnrs.
Now if there is one invalid field for one pnr, while validating the xml again schema, we are getting soap fault, and the validation seems stopped at the first error point.

So essentially if there are 100 pnrs in a flight, if one pnr has got a invalid field, the entire response is lost due to that one invalid pnr. 
The requirement is to reject a pnr if it has got an error, and send the response with the rest of the valid pnr.

How can I achieve this with spring xsd validation either by configuration or programmatically.

```
    <complexType name="DutBookings">
    <sequence>
        <element name="RecCount" type="long" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <element name="DutBooking" type="tns:DutBooking" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </sequence>
</complexType>  
<!--  -->   
<complexType name="DutBooking">
    <annotation>
        <documentation>
            This holds the booking record. 
            The frequent flyer details and airline customer value held at this level represents
            the highest tier / value for all passengers associated with the booking.
        </documentation>
    </annotation>
    <sequence>
        <element name="BookingReference" type="tns:FlightBookingReference" minOccurs="0"/>
        <element name="BookingDate" type="dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
        <element name="BookingStatus" type="tns:BookingStatus" minOccurs="0"/>
        <element name="BookingType" type="tns:BookingType" minOccurs="0"/>
        <element name="CreatingBookingOffice" type="tns:OfficeID" minOccurs="0"/>
        <element name="POSCity" type="tns:CityCode" minOccurs="0"/>
        <element name="POSCountry" type="tns:ISO_CountryCode" minOccurs="0"/>
        <element name="NameCount" type="tns:Count" minOccurs="0">
            <annotation>
                <documentation>Number of real names on booking, includes infants</documentation>
            </annotation>
        </element>
        <element name="ReservationCount" type="tns:Count" minOccurs="0">
            <annotation>
                <documentation>Count of passengers on booking, excludes infants</documentation>
            </annotation>
        </element>
        <element name="MaxAirlineCustomerValue" type="int" minOccurs="0"/>
        <element name="CabinCode" type="tns:CabinCode" minOccurs="0"/>
        <element name="BookingClass" type="tns:SellingClass" minOccurs="0"/>
        <element name="SplitCount" type="tns:Count" minOccurs="0">
                <annotation>
                    <documentation>Number of names split from the booking</documentation>
                </annotation>
        </element>
        <element name="SplitParentBookingReference" type="tns:FlightBookingReference" minOccurs="0"/>
        <element name="StaffNumber" type="tns:StaffNumber" minOccurs="0"/>
        <element name="StaffJoiningDate" type="date" minOccurs="0"/>
        <element name="StaffTravelPriorityCode" type="tns:StaffTravelPriorityCode" minOccurs="0"/>
        <element name="BookingPassenger" type="tns:BookingPassenger" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <element name="SuitabilityKeyword" type="tns:SuitabilityKeyword" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <element name="DutServiceLine" type="tns:DutServiceLine" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </sequence>
</complexType>
```

So you can see that there are dutbookings elements, inside which there is a list of dutbooking. if there is validation error in one booking I want to continue with the rest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you check an entire document, all of it checked against the schema.

A more programatic approach would be to validate the inner bookings list separately. Extract the list of booking elements and repackage the valid ones into a list, leaving out (and logging?) the ones that failed validation.

It does not seem like an option for you to redefine your schema to "allow optionals" or whatever is causing a pnr booking to fail. Then validation would pass, but it isn't exactly what you want.

Comment: All the validation rules are inscripted in the schema itself. If I try to do it programmatically, can I utilize the validation rules from the schema.

Comment: Schemas can be broken into pieces. And a "parent" schema can include another. So you could have "DutBookings.xsd" and "DutBooking.xsd". I would presume that that Spring Validation API (or at least JAXB does) would have calls to check a particular element against a particular schema. You would control the error flow (stop, continue, etc...)